# How to test a child component of a Styled Component? Jest and Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

In a project I am working on Unit test with Jest and enzyme. My component is a styled component that wraps around another component. My CvvFieldUi component uses TextField component of material UI. Here is my code

```
export class CvvFieldUI extends CvvFieldState {
  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    return (
      <TextField
        fullWidth
        type={!this.state.showCvv ? "password" : "text"}
        id="cvv-number"
        placeholder={this.state.placeHolder}
        value={this.state.cvvValue}
        className={clsx(classes.textField)}
        onChange={(event) => {
          this.handleChange(event);
          this.props.CVV(this.state.cvvValue);
        }}
        InputProps={{
          classes: { root: classes.inputField },
          endAdornment: (
            <InputAdornment position="end">
              <IconButton
                  aria-label="toggle password visibility"
                  onClick={(event) => this.handleClickShowPassword(event)}
                  onMouseDown={(event) => this.handleMouseDownPassword(event)}
              >
                {this.state.showCvv ? <Visibility /> : <VisibilityOff />}
              </IconButton>
            </InputAdornment>
          ),
        }}
        variant="outlined"
      />
    );
  }
}
CvvFieldUI.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(CvvFieldUI);
```

I want to test the state of this component. Here is my code.

```
test('Testing CVV Field', () => {
    /*const { getByText } = render(<App />);
    const linkElement = getByText(/learn react/i);
    expect(linkElement).toBeInTheDocument();*/
    const wrapper = shallow(
        <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <CvvFieldUI placeHolder="placeholder" CVV={()=>{}} />
        </MuiThemeProvider>
        ).dive();

    const input = wrapper.find(OriginalCvvField);

    console.log("Child",input.state().cvvValue.length);


});
```

What I have done is to get the unwrapped component from the styledcomponent. But when i do this it gives me error

> `ShallowWrapper::state() can only be called on the root`

It looks like I am unable to get unstyled component. 
**Question:**
How can I call state method on the component?

**UPDATE:**
Now I am testing visible out put but it is also not working. It does show me the `input`and its properties correctly but I am unable to manipulate it. When I display the value of input, it still shows null. Here is my code

```
const wrapper = mount(
        <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <CvvFieldUI placeHolder="placeholder" CVV={()=>{}} />
        </MuiThemeProvider>
        );
    const  Cvv=wrapper.find(OriginalCvvField);
    const input = Cvv.find('input');
    input.simulate('focus');
    input.simulate('change', { target: { value: 'Changed' } });
    console.log("Input tag",input.get(0));
```

Comment: 1. Are you sure you want to test styled component? Just test CvvFieldUI component. `Import { CvvFieldUI } from 'path/to/component/';`

2. It is not a good practice to test implementation details. Instead of checking the inner state of the component, it is much better to test its visible output.

Comment: Actually I am using the Css classes in the component.If I dont use the styled component it gives me error that it cannot find classes. specifically on thisline className={clsx(classes.textField)}

Comment: unless I pass props from outside. But that does not make sense to me.

Comment: Why doesn't it make sense?

Comment: I mean I can pass the classes as props but i think that would be data duplication. Same code is in the component and I would be again declaring those classes in my test.  Because what would be doing is I would be passing the same thing I want to test.

Comment: Also please see my update regarding your 2nd comment about testing visible output

Comment: You should not be scared of duplication here as it is just a passing input to your function (component). You want to test if an input reacts to the user interactions and changes its value - it is still in place. Also, that will cover receiving and applying the classes from props. Very useful.

Comment: Regarding interactions (focus, click, etc.) you probably need `mount` not a `shallow`.
Also, I'd suggest to switch to @testing-library/react

Comment: Is testing-library/react replacement of jest or enzyme?

Comment: For enzyme. Jest is still in place. 
Though you can use both enzyme and testing-library.